# Microsoft bot builder V4 nodejs fetching user email

Tags: node.js, botframework

i am using nodejs v4 version of the botbuilder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder/?view=botbuilder-ts-latest

My current code is picked from echo bot and looks like below

```
const { ActivityHandler } = require('botbuilder');

class ScanBuddyMsBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.onMessage(async (context:any, next:any) => {
            await context.sendActivity(`You said '${ context.activity.text }'`);

            // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
            await next();
        });
    }
}

module.exports.ScanBuddyMsBot = ScanBuddyMsBot;
```

I am looking a way to fetch user email sending message to my bot. I can see in the context activity, conversation id and service url but not the email id.

in another variation of this i am using below way to get email id and not sure how to make below code work for above

```
  var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, async function(session) {

        var teamId = session.message.address.conversation.id;
        connector.fetchMembers(
            session.message.address.serviceUrl,
                teamId,
            async (err, result) => {
              if (err) {
                session.send('We faced an error trying to process this information', err);
                return
              }
              else {
                const email = result[0].email
             }
```

Comment: What channel are you using?

Comment: microsoft teams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bot Builder v4, you can access that [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference#get-conversation-members) using the [`getConversationMembers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botframework-connector/conversations#getconversationmembers-string--requestoptionsbase-) function:

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {TurnContext} turnContext
 */
async testTeams(turnContext) {
    const activity = turnContext.activity;
    const connector = turnContext.adapter.createConnectorClient(activity.serviceUrl);
    const response = await connector.conversations.getConversationMembers(activity.conversation.id);
    const email = response[0].email;
    await turnContext.sendActivity(email);
}
```

Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service) and the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs) to better understand how to use the v4 SDK.